# Adding IBMs wala.cast.python.ml as dependency

Tags: gradle, build, maven-2, dependency-management

I am trying to build a project that has this dependency. The corresponding entry in the `build.gradle` file is like this.

```
implementation group: 'com.ibm.wala', name:'com.ibm.wala.cast.python.ml', version:'0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

When I run the command `./gradlew build` it failed to find the dependency. There is no point of searching the remote maven, because it is not there. The dependency is a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/wala/ML). The error says it looks for two local locations as well.

```
- file:/home/<user>/.m2/repository/com/ibm/wala/com.ibm.wala.cast.python.ml/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
- file:/home/<user>/.m2/repository/com/ibm/wala/com.ibm.wala.cast.python.ml/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/com.ibm.wala.cast.python.ml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

But, when I browse the content in `.m2/repository/com/ibm/wala` it has a directory `ML` which has the following.

```
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
|--maven-metadata-local.xml
|--ML-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
maven-metadata-local.xml
```

**maven-metadata-local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.ibm.wala</groupId>
  <artifactId>ML</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <versions>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20221028162537</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

**ML-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ibm.wala</groupId>
  <artifactId>ML</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project-version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</project-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <build-alias>b000</build-alias>
  </properties>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>internal.repo</id>
      <name>Temporary Staging Repository</name>
      <url>file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <modules>
    <module>com.ibm.wala.cast.python</module>
    <module>com.ibm.wala.cast.python.jython</module>
    <module>com.ibm.wala.cast.python.jython3</module>
    <module>com.ibm.wala.cast.python.test</module>
    <module>com.ibm.wala.cast.python.jython.test</module>
    <module>com.ibm.wala.cast.python.jython3.test</module>
    <module>com.ibm.wala.cast.python.ml</module>
    <module>com.ibm.wala.cast.python.ml.test</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

I tried to hack by creating a dir `com.ibm.wala.cast.python.ml`, then copying the content in ML to it. But it does not work.

Any ideas on how to include this dependency?